# Equation of a line passing through a given point, perpendicular with a line

Tags: euclidean-geometry, vectors

I need the equation  of the line passing through a given point $A(2,3,1)$ perpendicular to the given line
$$
\frac{x+1}{2}= \frac{y}{-1} = \frac{z-2}{3}.
$$

I think there must bee some kind of rule to do this, but I can't find it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you put point A in a plane that is perpendicular to given line, then the line you're looking for be in this plane, and could be found using the plane line intersection point and point A.
[image]

something like this.

1. So normal vector of the plane is the direction vector of the given line.
2. Point A is located in this plane
3. I can construct equation of the plane
4. I can find intersection point B, where line intersects the plane
5. Line you're looking for is the line passing through the points A and B.
   [image]

Calculus would look something like this:

$\vec c=(2,-1,3)=\vec{n_{\pi}}$

$2(x-x_A)-1(y-y_A)+3(z-z_A)=0$

$2(x-2)-1(y-3)+3(z-1)=0$

$2x-y+3z-4=0$

Line parametric:

$$x(t)=2t-1$$
$$y(t)=-t$$
$$z(t)=3t+2$$

Throw it in the plane equ:

$4t-2+t+9t+6-4=0\rightarrow t_B=0$

So coordinates of point B are: 
$$x(t_B)=2t-1=-1$$
$$y(t_B)=-t=0$$
$$z(t_B)=3t+2=2$$

We have now point B(-1,0,-2), we can construct direction vector of the line as $\vec{AB}$ we have a point on a line and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording (x+1)/2= y/-1 = (z-2)/3 looks strange. Why not  (x+1)/2= -y = (z-2)/3 ? Is there not a typing mistake ? If it's OK, an analylical method is shown below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The system looks over determined by the line's equation. However, one chooses the line between (2,3,1) and (-1,0,2). (I minimized the distance and got a result in agreement.) I thought it a bit of a trick question.

Comment: I don't agree that the system be over determined. The analytical solving leads to one solution and no more.